# Ember.js CollectionView and handlebars template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm new to ember.js and have a problem to display my collectionview:

```
    var KAListView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: 'kalist'
});
    App.TestlistView = KAListView.create({
    content: [
        {title : "item1",
         sub : "ceci est un sous titre"}"}
        ,
        {title : "item5",
         sub : "ceci est un sous titre"}
        ,
        {title : "item6",
         sub : "ceci est un sous titre"}
        ,
        {title : "item7",
         sub : "ceci est un sous titre"}
],
        itemViewClass: KAListElemView.extend({
        template: elemtemplate
    })
});
```

When i `appentTo('body')` this works but i want to add it to my template. I thougt that as the collectionview inheriths from `Ember.View` I could simply write `{{view App.TestlistView}}` but i get an error that my object is not a view.

How can I simply display a collection view in my template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `{{collection App.TestlistView}}` for `Collection` and more importantly it doesn't inherit from `Ember.View` It inherits from `Ember.ContainerView`